# I am unable to install my project packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was getting error installing `expressJs` to my packages. I have had to do an `npm cache clean --force` no sucess, then I deleted my `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, I try to reinstall packages using `npm i` I still got an error.

Now I deleted `node.js` from my pc windows 10 and downloaded and installed the latest node and tried to reinstall the project packages again. Now the error I get is this

```
$ npm i
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ncies":{"autoprefixer'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chioma Onyepere\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-28T20_26_29_676Z-debug.log
```

My app is built on nextJs

Here's the package.json

```
{
  "name": "ratethis",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "now-build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p %PORT%"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/infinity-web-development/ratethis"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/infinity-web-development/ratethis/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/infinity-web-development/ratethis#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^3.15.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "next": "^8.0.3",
    "next-images": "^1.1.1",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "now": "^15.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-polls": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "shallow-equal": "^1.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "next-antd-aza-less": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Apparently error is from my pc cause it works just fine on another pc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about npm, but I'd suggesting trying to have it verify the installs it's already done and somehow rewrite the package.json file from the existing installs.

> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html

Even though the install failed and the package.json doesn't show any traces of the install, there could be some artifact that only npm knows about that's getting in the way.